# How can we pass a C structure to Python?

Tags: python, c, cpython

I'm a new in both C and Python. These days, I'm learning to embed Python in C. As I am calling Python functions from C, I'd like to know, how can we pass a C structure to Python?

thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest thing to do is probably to [create a new type](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html) and implement `tp_getattr`, either returning the appropriate member of the struct or raising an exception depending on the argument passed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm working on it right now. I will probablly take your answer I think ^_^

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams The example there create python modules. Is there's any way just to create the new type, and _"register"_ to current C embedded interpreter ? I don't want to generate a python module. I want my existing C struct object to somehow get pass to the embedded python script , wherein I can read/modify the `struct` elements. (Sorry, its almost 4 year, and I'm asking this on this post)

Comment: @P0W: Your new type has to live in *some* module, whether you create it yourself or use an existing one.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank-you ! for reply  But I'm upto [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29086883/1870232), not able to figure how to put things together

Answer (score 2):

This [documentation](http://docs.python.org/extending/) on extending and/or embedding Python might get you started.

There is also the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes) library to dynamically load native DLLs and passing C-like structures in and out of them (completely from within Python).

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. But the problem here is embeding Python into C. I've seen 'ctypes' and I suppose it might be used in extendding Python by C.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not what you're looking for, but we use [LCM](http://code.google.com/p/lcm/) to share c structs between c/c++, python, java, and matlab programs over udp with multicast. It's very handy for doing robotics.