# Copy C structure to Python List

Tags: python, c, list, struct, extending

I am new to Python. I have written a C code extending Python to get certain values from another C module. The values are got as C Structures. I need to return C structure to Python.
For this I think, copying C structure to Python list would be good.

I have a structure like:

```
struct cStruct{
 int a;
 char* b;
 struct c;
}cStruct_t;
```

**How to return cStruct_t to Python???**

Regards,
solz

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we pass a C structure to Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734016/how-can-we-pass-a-c-structure-to-python)

Comment: @nouney: Not exactly. My problem is I have a C structre which I got from another C module. I need to return this C structure to Python.